# Gson failing to parse Month correctly

Tags: gson, date-format

Json Data:

```
"created_at":"2013-07-24 21:43:52"
```

Code to parse:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").create();
foo mfoo = gson.fromJson(Json, foo.class);
```

The resulting "created_at" field in the is January instead of July.   (2013-01-24 21:43:52)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DD` is **day in year**. So ... you get Jan 24th.

Change it to `dd`